# DataBinding to database for swt table

Tags: java, database, eclipse, data-binding, swt

Is there any way for connect to a database and write it to a table in java swt?
(like binding database for a gridview in C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so...
But you can make something like that...
Just do your operations in Pojo's set functions... if you want  to update your database instantly..